# RabbitMQ Federation Status econnrefused

Tags: rabbitmq

I've set up my Rabbitmq on a host and now when I click on "Federation Status" I get: Error detail:econnrefused.

Log doesn't show much either, how can I narrow it down and figure out what the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

'econnrefused' is erlang's tcp module error message, means tcp connection has been refused.
You can adjust the rabbitmq's configure file for printing rabbitmq's connection info message. 
It may be related to firewall configuration or plugin problem.

You should spend time for understanding where is rabbitmq's configuration file and how to adjust it and where is log output carefully.